# CSS Error at-rules or selector expected in vscode

Tags: css

I copied some css code from a website, but this part is giving me error

```
.pricing-table:hover{
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.36);
  /*error starts from this line*/
  .pricing-table__button{
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 35px;
    .pricing-table__button:before{
      top: -80%;
      transform: rotate(0deg);
      width: 100%;
    }
    .pricing-table__button:after{
      opacity: 1;
      padding-right: 15px;
    }
  }
}
```

Please is there anything wrong with the css code

source: https://codepen.io/DigimadMedia/pen/qZdMzd

Comment: That isn't valid CSS...

Comment: @BenM Please explain

Comment: It is SASS code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the code you are post in your question is `SASS`. you have to convert this css code to normal css.

the normal css code is as follow:

```
.pricing-table:hover{
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.36);
}
.pricing-table:hover .pricing-table__button:before{
  top: -80%;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  width: 100%;
}
.pricing-table:hover .pricing-table__button:after{
  opacity: 1;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.pricing-table:hover .pricing-table__button{
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 35px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct form is:

```
.pricing-table:hover{
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.36);
  }

.pricing-table__button{
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 35px;
}

.pricing-table__button:before{
      top: -80%;
      transform: rotate(0deg);
      width: 100%;
}

.pricing-table__button:after{
      opacity: 1;
      padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: it was not in bad form it was written in the SASS form

Comment: @KuldipKoradia Yes, that is right, I answered very hasty.